# get oracle scn with a schema from another schema

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, schema, storage

I have 2 schemas on my database, an admin (which contains all the tables) and a second schema which has grants to select, update, delete from synonym tables from admin. (I am using 11G)

I am working just with the admin schema.
What i am trying to do is, get the scn before an operation is done:

```
SELECT current_scn FROM V$DATABASE;
```

then some oeprations are done, and after that I am trying to make a select with the scn that i stored it before operations:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable AS OF SCN 2312312;
```

and then

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

this error is coming.

Comment: Have you asked your DBA to give you permission to perform a flashback query?

Comment: well, I have the position to be the DBA.. but which command is that?          if i execute query on the admin schema is it working, but on the other schema i am able just to get the scn, but not use it in query on tables from admin...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grant the user privileges to run a flashback query against the table.

```
grant flashback 
   on myTable
   to someUser;
```

Or you can give the user privileges to run flashback queries against any table

```
grant flashback any table
   to someUser
```

Generally, auditors get rather nervous when they see the various "any" privileges but this one is reasonably safe.  You may also want to grant privileges on the `dbms_flashback` package as well.

The documentation has a good overview of the [administrative tasks to enable flashback features](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_fl.htm#1009344).

Comment: this thing worked! thank you! I had to give privileges to flashback any table.   grant execute on dbms_flashback to schema;
grant flashback any table to schema;